# Delete Opened File by Explorer

Tags: shell, dll, nsis

I create a shell extension (DLL) that work properly, But when using the Uninstaller to remove the program that DLL not removed becuase it opened by Windows Explorer & i must use TaskManager to first close Explorer.exe then run it again and delete manualy that file (Shell Extenstion Dll),
Now my qustion is, How to delete Shell Extestion files in the Uninstaller script? I use Nullsoft Scriptable Install System 2.46 (NSIS) to create Setup program.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to uninstall shell extensions on Windows.

Your best option is to try to delete the .dll and fall back to a reboot: `Delete /RebootOK "$InstDir\MyExt.dll"`.

Another alternative is to try to move the .dll to %temp%. This will not unload the extension but it will allow you to delete everything else and the extension will not load the next time the user logs in. (This will only work if it is on the same volume as %temp%?)

It is important to remember that any application that uses the Open/Save common dialog or internally uses `SHGetFileInfo()`, `IShellFolder` or `IShellItem` could have loaded your extension so just killing Explorer might not be enough.